# Open Audio File format supported for streaming in flash player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, open-source, audio-streaming

I am trying to stream audio to my flash application. I got it working with a test MP3 file. But the problem is that MP3 encoders are protected by patents and require license fees.(I am living in Canada) Isn't there a open audio file format supported by flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a library to play ogg vorbis -- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816701/using-ogg-vorbis-in-flash-flex-applications). I've used it myself to stream internet radio and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I downloaded the library from http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy:Libraries , but I cannot find any examples on how to use the library. It would be nice if you could provide me with a little example.